# Changing the month in MonthCalendar fires DateChanged event twice

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

Heyo,

I have a standard WinForms MonthCalendar in my application with a handler hooked up to the DateChanged event. Whenever I change the date by day, clicking on a certain date in the little calendar, the event fires once. However, whenever I change the date by month, clicking on the < and > in the control, the event fires twice. I want the event to fire once in all situations.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I debugged and found out that the SelectedItem or Range is the same on the first and second handler call. So I need a way to differentiate between the first and second call while still allowing for proper handling when the event only fires once.

The handler code was requested, here it is, but it has nothing to do with the event firing multiple times:

```
List<TimestampInfo> displayTimestamps = databaseManger.QueryForTimestamps(DayPicker.SelectionRange);
if (displayTimestamps == null) return;
TimestampsListBox.Items.Clear();
TimestampsListBox.Items.AddRange(displayTimestamps.ToArray());
```

Comment: Please share SelectedDateChanged event handler code

Comment: Just write your eventhandler so that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Someone with the same problem as you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8a1d9322-d837-4b86-bb4f-5444e5ddbee2 .  The fix seems to be either a flag or remove and add the event again.

Comment: Carl: That is not the same problem, I am not changing the SelectedDate from code.

Henk: What does that even mean?

Comment: The event will fire as the month part of the date is changing, you will need to handle what's happening in the event accordingly and only output what you need it to.

Comment: Kev: Right, but why the control changes the date twice when the user changes the date once is beyond me.

Comment: Very hard to understand this question, there is no SelectedDateChanged event in Winforms.  Are you actually talking about WPF?

Comment: Hans: my apologies, I am referring to the DateChanged event of the System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar control.

Comment: You need to think this through a bit.  Supposed you get the event to fire only once (which it does in later Windows versions).  What do you hope to happen if the user needs to scroll by *two* months?

Comment: Hans: Please refer to this image: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/images/monthcal.jpg

The user is unable to scroll by two months at a time using this control. The user would click the < or > twice, firing the handler exactly twice, once for each click. These are the requirements.

Comment: @Frimace - in a well written Event handling system a repeated Changed event should not cause a problem. It's not a Click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat of a hack, but compare the `SelectionRange` string value with the last `DataChanged` event.  Just run your code if it's different:

```
private string _LastRange = string.Empty;

private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e) {
  if (monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.ToString() != _LastRange) {
    _LastRange = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.ToString();

    List<TimestampInfo> displayTimestamps = databaseManger.QueryForTimestamps(DayPicker.SelectionRange);
    if (displayTimestamps == null) return;
    TimestampsListBox.Items.Clear();
    TimestampsListBox.Items.AddRange(displayTimestamps.ToArray());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the handler running twice, though it does not prevent the event from firing twice. Perhaps I will file a bug report.

Comment: @Grimace As Hans mentioned, the event firing twice was fixed in VS2010.  MS is probably not going to fix this issue in earlier versions.

Comment: @Grimace Hmmm, the event firing twice only happened on my vs2008 version, not vs2010 when I tested it.  Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this until I hooked up the event handler twice.

```
monthCalendar1.DateChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventHandler(this.monthCalendar1_DateChanged);
monthCalendar1.DateChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventHandler(this.monthCalendar1_DateChanged);
```

Is you code munging around with the event handlers?

Comment: The handler is only set once in the auto-generated MainForm.Designer.cs file. Are you sure you reproduced it? Like the OP says, the event only fires once if the user clicks on a date in the calendar instead of on the < or > buttons.

Comment: Yeah I caught that.  I was wondering if he was munging around during the date click which would setup the weird behavior in the month click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e) {
      Calendar1.SelectedDate = Calendar1.VisibleDate;
      //  any additional code optional
}
```